Webresource form in power apps API show 401 error
I created web-resource form using html,JavaScript and jQuery  when I deployed in power application the API show error

401 (unauthorized)

and not working. When deployed we used below script also for access data  from data verse:
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
datatype: "json",
url: "[Org_Name]/api/data/v9.2/[Table and requested fiels]",
beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
},
async: false,
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
var results = data;
for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {}
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
}});

below script are also used for data transaction
<script src="../WebResources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>

